# How to set ImageView image using URI?

Tags: java, android

I'm using the camera in my app. When I take the picture, the photo is saved correctly on the emulator's sdcard (I checked using Android Device Manager). Here's the code I used to save the photo:

```
private class AddPhotoButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        String fileName = "/sdcard/note_photo_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
        Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName));

        Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);

        note.photo = fileName;

        startActivityForResult(camera, REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PICTURE);
    }
}
```

This works without any errors. The file is saved in: storage/emulated/0/

I am handling the result from the camera as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(note.photo);
        ivPreview.setImageURI(null);
        ivPreview.setImageURI(imgUri);
        ivPreview.getLayoutParams().width = 120;
    }
}
```

However, this generates the following error: E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/note_photo_1480094620584.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

My app manifest permissions are set as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"></uses-feature>
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Are you running on `Android 6.0`?

Comment: Yes, the emulator is 6.0.

Comment: if you are sure that the image exists, it could be because of missing runtime permissions:https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html. Another scenario is, that your storage is not mounted, that happens for example on cyanogenMods. On that system, The storages are not mounted by default and you have to do it manually.

Comment: [Check this link](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for requesting permissions on `Android 6.0`. Or you can try running your code on emulators lower than `Android 6.0`

Comment: @NecipAllef thanks - that fixed the issue. However, every time I take a picture, the permission dialogue is displayed. Is this how it's meant to work? Should it not only require permission once?

Comment: Are you checking whether permission exists or not before requesting it?

Comment: Missed that, it's fixed now, thanks.